ADXL345, how to use the inactivity and activity thresholds?
In: Register 0x30—INT_SOURCE (Read Only)
Docs
If i read D3 for instance.
As i understand, the sensor takes some samples and if the acceleration has been lower than the specified threshold for the specified amount of time it tells me 1, an activity event was detected.
But what is happening under the hood? What is it reporting back and how did it arrive there?
Is it taking the sqrt of x^2 + y^2 + z^2 and calculates an average or what is it doing?
I read an amount of x, y, z and  then i applied this function on every row:
def cvm(x, y):
    result = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    return result

I tried feeding first the average as thresh_act and then the max as thresh_act and It doesn't really work for me.
I would really like to know how the sensor arrived at the value it compares to my value.
